# How to create a Json from an SQL query?

Tags: node.js

I have query the SQL 2 columns ID & Name using the OracleDb NPM package. After looping I am getting the following result:

```
[ 201, 'should load all Operations page Sub Menus' ]
    [ 203, 'should load all admin page Sub Menus' ],
    [ 202, 'should load all Approvals page Sub Menus' ],
    [ 204, 'should load all Reporting page Sub Menus' ]
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Please provide your nodeJS code and then ask for assistance if you're stuck.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Are you trying to store the name under the id inside the same object ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

The query result is returned as an object array : `results` 
Example : using `results[0].id` gets the first results row's id.

 With the following example you store the `name` *value* under the `id` *key*.

```
 var JSONObj = {};
    for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
       var this_id = results[i].id;
       JSONObj[this_id] = results[i].name;
    }
```

Resulting in a final object with this structure:

```
{ 201:'should load all Operations page Sub Menus', 
  203:'should load all admin page Sub Menus', 
  ...etc... }
```